# JavaScript - Sort objects by value but return key

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, key-value

I have an Object like this:

```
object = {A: 15, B: 30, C: 22}
```

So I'm sorting it using its values. For that, I have this function:

```js
object = {
  A: 15,
  B: 30,
  C: 22
}
function sortObjsValues(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a < b) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
}

console.log(sortObjsValues(object)); // => returns 30,22,15
```

Is there a way to return its keys instead of its values, keeping sorting by its values? The final result would be `B,C,A`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get entries from the object, sort by value descending and map the keys.

```js
const
    object = { A: 15, B: 30, C: 22 },
    getSortedKeys = o => Object
        .entries(o)
        .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
        .map(([k]) => k);

console.log(getSortedKeys(object));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just sort the keys by the value.

```js
const object = { A: 15, B: 30, C: 22 };

console.log(Object.keys(object).sort((a, b) => object[b] - object[a]));
```